# Error while running PySpark DataProc Job due to python version

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I create a dataproc cluster using the following command

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create datascience \
--initialization-actions \
    gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
```

However when I submit my PySpark Job I got the following error

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.4 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Did you install python on dataproc cluster for Jupyter notebook ?

Comment: Yes I use Jupyter image in the initialization-actions

Comment: This installed python version(3.7) on the driver node is conflicting with the python version on (3.4). So, try installing Jupyter notebook with Python(3.4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a difference in the python versions between the master and the worker. By default, the `jupyter image` installs the latest version of miniconda, which uses the python3.7. However, the worker is still using the default python3.6.

Solution:
- specify the miniconda version when creating the master node i.e to install python3.6 in the master node

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create example-cluster --metadata=MINICONDA_VERSION=4.3.30
```

Note:

- may need updating to have a more sustainable solution to managing the environment

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE THE SPARK ENVIRONMENT TO USE PYTHON 3.7:

Open a new terminal and type the following command: `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.7` This will ensure that the worker nodes use Python 3.7 (same as the Driver) and not the default Python 3.4

DEPENDING ON VERSIONS OF PYTHON YOU HAVE, YOU MAY HAVE TO DO SOME INSTALL/UPDATE ANACONDA:

(To install see:    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart)

Make sure you have anaconda 4.1.0 or higher. Open a new terminal and check your conda version by typing into a new terminal:

```
conda --version
```

**checking conda version**

if you are below anaconda 4.1.0, type `conda update conda`

2. Next we check to see if we have the library nb_conda_kernels by typing

`conda list`

Checking if we have `nb_conda_kernels`

3. If you don’t see `nb_conda_kernels` type

`conda install nb_conda_kernels`

Installing `nb_conda_kernels`

4. If you are using Python 2 and want a separate Python 3 environment please type the following

`conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel`

py35 is the name of the environment. You could literally name it anything you want.

Alternatively, If you are using Python 3 and want a separate Python 2 environment, you could type the following.

`conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel`

py27 is the name of the environment. It uses python 2.7.

5. Ensure the versions of python are installed successfully and close the terminal. Open a new terminal and type `pyspark`. You should see the new environments appearing.

Answer (score 2):

We fixed it now -- thanks for the intermediate workaround @brotich. Check out the discussion in [#300](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/300).

PR [#306](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/306) keeps python at the same version as was already installed (3.6), and installs packages on all nodes to ensure that the master and worker python environments stay identical.

As a side effect, you can choose your python version by passing an argument to the conda init action to change the python version. E.g. `--metadata 'CONDA_PACKAGES="python==3.5"'`.

PR [#311](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/311) pins miniconda to a particular version (currently 4.5.4), so we avoid issues like this again. You can use `--metadata 'MINICONDA_VERSION=latest'` to use the old behavior of always downloading the latest miniconda.